# postMessage to Web Worker is not working in React App with TypeScript + Webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, web-worker

I'm trying to post a message to a web worker in a React app developed with TypeScript and Webpack, but it's not working and doesn't throw any errors as well.

This is how I initialized the Web Worker.

**insights.ts**

```
export class Insights {
   private insightsWorker: Worker;

   constructor(){
      this.insightsWorker = new Worker(new URL('./insights.worker.js', import.meta.url), {type: 'module'});
   }

   public track(){
     this.insightsWorker.postMessage("track")
   }

}
```

The code in the worker file is as follows.

**insights.worker.js**

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    console.log("Message from parent:", event);
});
```

When the track method is called, I want the worker to execute and print the event, but it's not happening for some reason and there are no errors in the console as well.

Is there anyone who can point me to the right direction? Thanks in Advance.

EDIT 01:

I modified the worker code as follows,as per @calido 's suggestion, but still nothing can be seen on the console.

```js
console.log("Hellooo")

self.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    console.log("Message from parent:", event);
});

self.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
    console.log("error from parent:", event);
});
```

Comment: You can start by adding an error event listener on your Worker, then add a simple unconditional log in the worker script and see if it's executed.

Comment: @Kaiido Tried as described in `EDIT 01`, but nothing gets printed out to the console. :-(

Comment: I said to add it to your Worker not to your worker context. If "Hellooo" isn't printed that means there is an error before.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand exactly what you are saying. Can you elaborate a bit more, preferably with some sample code?

Comment: `this.insightsWorker = new Worker(new URL...); this.insightsWorker.onerror = console.error`

Comment: Thanks. tried it, but still didn't see any error in the console.

Comment: Then are you sure your code even reaches this line?

Answer (score 0):

Check you path of the worker again. This is what was happening in my case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34348726)